# Fetching Backward data make the chart stuck for a while with lightweight chart

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

using lightweight chart and swiftui / uikit, fetching backward data when the user swipes back. it works using setData.

the thing is you see a hiccup where the chart stops for a second. especially when the data gets bigger.

I append all the points in one array and give it to the chart

`DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.series.setData(data: sortedDP) }`

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Using `setData` will replace the entire data for that series and make the chart essentially draw that series from scratch. This may lead to the 'hiccup'.

Since you are adding data to 'past', you can't make use of the `update` method. So you are using the correct method.

**Potential solutions will depend on your specific use-case.**

If possible it might make sense to load all the data at the start and limit what is visible using either the `barSpacing` property ([link](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#barspacing)) or `setVisible` ([link](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#setvisiblerange)).

If this is not possible and the chunks of data (for the past) aren't too numerous then it might make sense to rather create a separate series for each data update (and ensure that the options are the same so that the chart looks correct). This way the chart doesn't need to reprocess the existing data again.

Comment: multiple series is a great idea! it helped a lot, thank you